# How do you test if the AWS load balancer is working?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've created a load balancer from the AWS console. With the generated url, how can I test that it is actually working? Curling or accessing it from a browser is not working. The load balancer url looks like

```
internal-site-123456.us-east-3.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Curling or pinging the http/https version of the above doesn't work.

**EDIT**

Turns out that I forgot to curl it with the port number. I can test it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four quick things come to mind:

1. Verify that the ELB health checks are passing on your backend instances.
2. Examine your ELB logs to verify that it's able to connect to your back-end instances.
3. Examine your application logs to see if the ELB is connecting.
4. Perform packet captures on your backend instances to see if the ELB is even attempting to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Check CloudWatch metrics for either the ELB or the instances behind the ELB. This obviously only works once it's been fully set up.